# error when changing string to json javascript

Tags: javascript, python

EDITED:

I have a dictionary that I got from a python script in a javascript variable.

```
"{
  u'aaaa': { 'name': u'a' },
  u'bbbb': { 'name': u'b' },
  u'cccc': { 'name': u'c' },
  u'dddd': { 'name': u'd' }
}"
```

It is in the variable `dict`.  Because it has `u` before some of the keys and values because it was a python dict I cannot convert it to  a json.

I get the error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 1`
what to do in order to parse it to json?
or there is a way to make a dictionary in python without `u` in the keys and values?

Comment: hmset expects a dict as the second argument, why do you convert it to json?

Comment: because I want to remove the u before the keys and the values that the python object do

Comment: Do you know what `u` mean?

Comment: yes, it means unicode but when if it stays in that format i cant parse it to an object after i fetch the dictionary from the redis

Comment: Don't create this string representation in the first place. Create JSON with the `json` module.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript just fix the string before casting the string as JSON. You can run the following in the console of a web browser, for instance:

```
var pythonOutput = "{ \
  u'aaaa': { 'name': u'a' }, \
  u'bbbb': { 'name': u'b' }, \
  u'cccc': { 'name': u'c' }, \
  u'dddd': { 'name': u'd' } \
}"    

JSON.parse(pythonOutput.replace(/\u'|'/ig, '"'))
```

This regular expression (h/t @IshmeetSingh) replaces all instances of `u'` with `"` and all instances of `'` with `"` (as the JSON spec requires double quotes).

Really the right way to solve this problem is to fix the Python code that generates the output. To write a Python dictionary to disk as JSON (so that it can be read into JavaScript), do:

```
import json

d = {'hi': 'mom'}

with open('hi.json', 'w') as out:
  json.dump(d, out)
```

If it's the case that your Python code has a variable that looks like the dict you posted above, you can convert that object to JSON in a way that's similar to the JavaScript solution above:

```
import json

d = """{
  u'aaaa': { 'name': u'a' },
  u'bbbb': { 'name': u'b' },
  u'cccc': { 'name': u'c' },
  u'dddd': { 'name': u'd' }
}"""

clean = d.replace("u'",'"').replace("'",'"')

dict_as_json = json.loads(clean)
```

If this doesn't help, I'd try to phrase your question more exactly -- which language has access to exactly what variable and what's the challenge in passing that variable elsewhere?

Comment: but if one of my values have `"` in it? it will change it.

Comment: `a.replace(/u'|'/ig, '"')` This should be the regex.

Comment: Thanks @IshmeetSingh. GandalfTheGray two possible solutions to that problem 1) Escape double quotes in values before persisting, or 2) actually save JSON to disk from Python. I edited my answer to show how you can do that properly...

Comment: I want my dict to be of type `dict` and not type `str`
because the redis function in the python script gets a `dict`

Comment: @Gandalf did you see my edits above? We create a dictionary named `d` and persist it to disk as JSON. Try calling `print(type(d))` in that example. That waren't no string, that was a hazy cosmic dict.

Comment: yes, however the dict i have has the `u` in its keys and values in the python `dict` object

Comment: @GandalfTheGray those u's are just something Python 2.7 shows when you print a unicode string. If you use the `json.dump()` method you'll save your dictionary as JSON and will then be able to consume it from JavaScript. Also, you shouldn't name variables `dict` as that's a reserved term in Python (it's used to cast objects to type dictionary or initialize a new dictionary)

Comment: the `dict` was just for this example :P... ill explain my situation again,
I got from some db a dictionary :

` {

      u'aaaa': { 'name': u'a' },

      u'bbbb': { 'name': u'b' },

      u'cccc': { 'name': u'c' },

      u'dddd': { 'name': u'd' }

}`

i want to have it as a `dict` type, when i do json.dumps(dict) it gives me a it in type `str`.
and if i try to do json.loads(dict) after i did dumps it returns to the first state.

Comment: @Gandalf save JSON to the db not a dictionary. Good luck!

Comment: @GandalfTheGray I really don't understand your problem. You can't have both, you must decide if you need a string containing JSON or if you need a Python dictionary, type `dict`, which you get from the database. Just a hunch: You may misinterpret what you see and suspect a problem where there actually is none.